# PHP_SELF on submit form

Tags: php, forms, get, isset

I have a question about using PHP_SELF on a submit from a form.
This is what I have in my **index.php**:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <?php
                    // If you get an appid, 
                    if(isset($_GET['appid'])) {
                        // GET appid
                        $appid = $_GET['appid'];

                        $json_url  ='http://api.nameurl.com/api/gateway/call/1.4/getApp?appid=' . $appid;

                        $ch = curl_init($json_url);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

                        $str = curl_exec($ch);
                        curl_close($ch);

                        $data = json_decode($str);
                        $array = json_encode($data);
                    }  
                    else if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                        $name = $_POST['appid'];
                        echo "User Has submitted the form and entered this name : <b> $name </b>";
                        echo "<br>You can use the following form again to enter a new name."; 
                    }
                    else{ ?>
                        <!-- Form -->
                        <form class="well" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">  
                            <label>Your appid</label>  
                            <input type="text" class="span3" name="appid" id="appid" placeholder="Type your appid here...">  <br>
                            <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="Loading...">Submit</button>  
                        </form>

                <?php }   
                ?>

                <p id="errors" class="text-error"></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr>

    </div>
```

I check if I get an appid from the previous page. 
Yes -> get data from api
No -> Show the form so you can insert an appid

Then when you press on submit on the form I want to get the appid
insert and do the same operations as above.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the value of `form's action` because you're processing the form in the same page. And replace the `method` from `post` to `get`.

Comment: Your form method is set to POST. You are using GET to check for appid

Comment: if you using method post you should try with $_POST['appid'] instead of $_GET['appid']

Comment: Sorry id, stupid mistake! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the method for the form set to `post`, but you're trying to access the appid using `$_GET['appid']`. You either need to change the form method to `get`, or access the appid using `$_POST['appid']`

Answer (score 3):

Try this....

```
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                    <?php
                        // If you get an appid, 
                        if(isset($_GET['appid'])) {
                            // GET appid
                            $appid = $_GET['appid'];

                            $json_url  ='http://api.nameurl.com/api/gateway/call/1.4/getApp?appid=' . $appid;

                            $ch = curl_init($json_url);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

                            $str = curl_exec($ch);
                            curl_close($ch);

                            $data = json_decode($str);
                            $array = json_encode($data);
                        }  
                        else if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                            $name = $_POST['appid'];
                            echo "User Has submitted the form and entered this name : <b> $name </b>";
                            echo "<br>You can use the following form again to enter a new name."; 
                        }
                        else{ ?>
                            <!-- Form -->
                            <form class="well" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">  
                                <label>Your appid</label>  
                                <input type="text" class="span3" name="appid" id="appid" placeholder="Type your appid here...">  <br>
                                <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />  
                            </form>

                    <?php }   
                    ?>

                    <p id="errors" class="text-error"></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no $_POST['submit'] being defined. 
The reason is that the button doesn't have the `name="submit"` attribute

Answer (score 0):

name missing in submit button

```
  <button type="submit" name ="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="Loading...">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you defined method action as **POST** but you retrieve it as **GET** you can use also **$_REQUEST** to get variables from both post/get request.

Changing this

```
if(isset($_GET['appid'])) {
                    // GET appid
                    $appid = $_GET['appid'];
```

to

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['appid'])) {
                    // GET appid
                    $appid = $_REQUEST['appid'];
```

solves case as well.

> The variables in $_REQUEST are provided to the script via the GET, POST, and COOKIE input mechanisms and therefore could be modified by the remote user and cannot be trusted. The presence and order of variables listed in this array is defined according to the PHP variables_order configuration directive.

http://php.net/manual/pl/reserved.variables.request.php